# Super User Tag Dropdown busted

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I'm seeing a big problem with the Tag Dropdown on Super User only.  Using Windows 7 64-bit and IE 9.

[image: Bad Tag Dropdown]

Comment: The tag dropdown where? Can you give us a link to a page the problem occurs on?

Comment: You've flushed your cache as well?

Comment: Sure, [here is the example one](http://superuser.com/questions/329615/vim-make-f-t-f-t-continue-on-line-breaks), just edit the tags.  BUT, I've had this happen on three different questions today.

Comment: @random, no, I hate that as much as I hate rebooting the computer to fix problems, but now that I've reported it, I'll do that.  Note, it isn't happening on the other sites.

Comment: @Lance I can't reproduce the problem in IE9 on Windows 7 x64, both logged in and anonymously, for editing or posting a new question. It all seems to work just fine.

Comment: Also my gosh, do you use everything on 200% zoom? Why is your screenshot so _big_?

Comment: @nhinkle, I have a 27" screen, maxed out, so then I zoom in, looks pretty normal when using it.  I just did the cache flush, restarted the browser and the problem fixed itself.  Guess it will be status-norepro, but of course if it can happen once, it'll happen again.

Comment: I can't repro that but do get this tag wackyness: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3KAxI.png in IE9 on Win7 x64 and that's after a full cache flush and restart.

Comment: I hear IE9 breaks a lot of pages...have you considered another browser?

Comment: @Simon, I'm tired of the Firefox bugs that they won't fix, and Chrome had something wrong that escapes me right now.

Comment: I can reproduce Kev's behavior using **Compatibility Mode** while everything looks fine without it, perhaps your drop-down issue is related to that (in combination with the zoom, no clue what level your at)? Are you sure you haven't set a different renderer / compatibility mode in the F12 Developer Tools?

Comment: @tom - ah you're right. Just noticed that compatibility view was turned on for all sites which is why it wasn't showing the broken page icon. Another one of the reasons why I abandoned IE for chrome many moons ago.

Comment: Hmmm, I had used compatibility mode on a different site and tab, but maybe that one was being affected.

Answer (score 1):

Can't repro in IE9, see my screenshot.. all defaults, I never touch IE9:

[image]

Are you using any kind of non-default settings or zoom?